# NodeJS uptime and the epoch

Tags: node.js, date

The following code calculates the epoch time of boot.

```
console.log(Math.floor(new Date() /1000) - os.uptime())
```

It should be constant, but there is a 1-second anomaly.

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1):

The OS doesn't necessarily start exactly on the second boundary.  While you're getting OS uptime down to the second, it may have came up part of the way through a second.

Comment: I understand. Thx.